# Why is my getUserPrincipal() not a instanceof KeycloakPrincipal?

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus

I'm working at a project that uses keycloak and quarkus. `For this project I would need the ID of a logged in user. To retrieve the ID I used the code below.

The problem with this is that principal is not a instace of keycloak, why is this?
Do i need set a specific setting for this? So yea can someone point me in the right direction.

```
@Path("/api/users")
public class UserResource {
    
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserResource.class);

    @Inject
    SecurityIdentity identity;

    @Context
    SecurityContext sc;

    @GET
    @Path("/me")
    @NoCache
    public String me() {
        
        String userName = sc.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        logger.info(userName);
        if (sc.getUserPrincipal() instanceof KeycloakPrincipal) {
        KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> kp = (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>)  sc.getUserPrincipal();

            logger.info("pricipal is keycloak principal");

            userName = kp.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getSubject();
        }
        return userName;
    }
}
```

This is the payload of the token.

```
{
    "exp": 1670882964,
    "iat": 1670882664,
    "auth_time": 1670882663,
    "jti": "1f7bcd19-2641-456f-a77c-05150cffef71",
    "iss": "http://localhost:8180/realms/quarkus",
    "sub": "b79a8a40-1cbc-48a5-82b0-fadd9e25fb8d",
    "typ": "Bearer",
    "azp": "quarkus-app",
    "nonce": "nHaSpEC",
    "session_state": "5dbab352-b6be-4403-ab6e-0bd2d43a7425",
    "acr": "1",
    "scope": "openid microprofile-jwt address profile",
    "sid": "5dbab352-b6be-4403-ab6e-0bd2d43a7425",
    "upn": "bob",
    "address": {},
    "groups": [
        "user"
    ],
    "preferred_username": "bob"
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you end up solving this?